# Show that if $a$ has order $2k \text{(mod p)}$ for an integer $k$, then $a^{k} \equiv -1 \text{(mod p)}$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $(a,p)=1$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Show that if $a$ has order $2k \text{(mod p)}$ for an integer $k$, then $a^{k} \equiv -1 \text{(mod p)}$.

My attempt is that since $a$ has order $2k,$ then $a^{2k} \equiv 1 \text{(mod p)}$, which means that $(a^{2})^{k} \equiv 1 \text{(mod p)}$. But how can I use primality of $p$?

Comment: Hint:  primality of $p$ tells us that $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod p$ has only two solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $a^{2k}-1 = (a^k+1)(a^k-1)$ and thus $p \mid (a^k-1)(a^k+1)$. Therefore by Euclid's Lemma either $a^k \equiv 1\pmod{p}$ or $a^k \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. The former case is impossible since $2k$ is the order of $a$ modulo $p$. Thus $a^k \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are there almost. Instead of using $(a^2)^k\equiv1\pmod p$, the other one $(a^k)^2\equiv1\pmod p$ is more convenient. Now  $a^k\equiv1\pmod p$ will make $a$'s order $k$ or less, contradicting the hypothesis that the order is $2k$.

Now use the fact that $f(x)=x^2$ is a 2-to-1 function  on nonzero elements of  $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ as $f(x)=f(-x)$. (It is a group homomorphism and can apply fundamental isomorphism theorem). ( for $p$  odd prime).

Comment: Thank you - it's interesting, but my class is introductory number theory and abstract algebra is not a prerequisite. So, I think I can't use factor groups or homo/isomorphisms.

Comment: I put that group-theoretic remark in parenthesis suspecting it. I have given enough info. Instead of homomorphism reformulate it as:  if two elements are squares then their product is also a square. When you multiply a square with a non-square result is a non-square. Product of two non-squares is a square. By non-square I mean the elements  outside the image of $f$ (among non-zero elements). This will accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

$Z/pZ$ is a field so $a^{2k}-1=(a^k+1)(a^k-1)=0$ mod p is equivalent to the fact  that $a^k =1$ mod p or $a^k=-1$ mod p.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not that familiar with fields and so I chose the previous user's answer, and because it was first.